# Get ID of all link button in row command event which is present in header template of gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am facing problem with asp.net grid view since long time.

I have used grid view. In header template there is link button for sorting.

i want change the style of link button used for sorting.

I have used row command event for sorting.

I want to get the ID of each link button which is present in each header templates in row command event of grid view.

Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be as easy as this

```
LinkButton yourLinkButton = (LinkButton)Gridview1.HeaderRow.FindControl("yourLinkButton");
yourLinkButton.CssClass="mystyle";
```